# How to obtain the list of pixels/fragments generated by the fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es

The fragment shader draws to the framebuffer.

But how can I efficiently obtain just the pixels/fragments generated as a result of execution
of the fragment shader?

Comment: What do you mean by **obtain**?

Comment: obtain as in get the full list in an array or list, or get a pointer to the same of just the changed pixels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Setup a stencil mask so each time you draw a fragment, it will set that mask to 1.
- Retrieve the stencil mask and the color buffer with glReadPixels function.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, you don't.

You could have the fragment shader write a specific color value to an image. Then you can read back from the image and test where that color is. That would get you the information you want. If you write to a floating-point framebuffer, you can even use an additive blend mode so that you can see how much you write to each sample location.

But that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

> The fragment shader draws to the framebuffer.

Not directly. Although later versions of OpenGL support scatter operation in the fragment shader, gather execution comes more natural to it.

Before the fragment processing stage is executed, the rastering stage first determines, which fragments get written to by the currently processed primitive. This happens through a scanline range estimator or such. I.e. the set of fragments processed is determined before execution of the fragment shader. The only thing the fragment shader then does is computing the values used by the following blending stage to combine into the framebuffer.